# EXCEL: Remove blanks from Dropdown List & make Dropdown List inactive if no options are returned?

Tags: excel-formula

I use a Unique Filter formula to obtain a list. I do not want any blanks in my Dropdown List at all.

Problem,
1: How can I remove the blanks?
2: If the list returns no options can I make the Dropdown List inactive?
3: How can I have the first or all dropdown list options displayed in the cell, before clicking on it with a mouse?

I tried selecting REMOVE BLANKS in Data Validation but the blanks still show up.

IMAGE[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JbGQ.png

Comment: to problem 1: Removing the blanks from the drop down menu would only work with a "helper array". You've already written the solution for such an array in cell N6. Simply make in an actual array and make the list refer to that array dynamically. Problem 2 and 3 are not possible with simple data validation.

Comment: Thank you Dattel. 

I am still having trouble though.

ISSUE: Entering a fixed range into Data Validation for Dropdown.

Dropdown options vary for each product. 
* One product may have 50 x dropdown options, where,
* Another product will only have 3 options.

Data validation source will not accept the formula '=(UNIQUE(Z12:CT12))'

When I select a fixed range for data validation, I get a long list of blanks with my options. Finding a solution (either in Excel or Google Sheets), will result when I click on the dropdown there is only options and no blanks.

Hoping to hear from you.

Comment: Hi Dattel, I take that back, Google Sheets is removing the blanks now. So I have convert the document into Sheets for now.. Thank you!!!